# Detect when ema 50 is at Rsi level 90 or ema 50 is at rsi level 10, when ema 50 is placed on same rsi window

Tags: bots, mql4, metatrader4, forex, mt4

Hello fellow trader and programmer, I wanted to build an EA for a strategy, and the strategy entails that I place ema 50 on the same rsi window and I will place a buy order when rsi is at level 30 or below and ema 50 is at rsi level 10 or below. then I will place a sell order when rsi is at level 70 or above and ema 50 is at rsi level 90 or above. I know I can get the value of rsi with the IRSI() function. But how can I detect when ema 50 is at rsi level 90. or when ema 50 is at rsi level 10?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know the Close value for each of the point in chart history when RSI() was above/below certain level? Or do you want to know the current Bid/Ask if RSI() is above/below certain level in real time?

Comment: @user3666197

the issue is that I wanted to build an EA for a strategy, and the strategy entails that I place ema 50 on the same rsi window

and I will place a buy order when rsi is at level 30 or below and ema 50 is at rsi level 10  or below.

then I will place a sell order when rsi is at level 70 or above and ema 50 is at rsi level 90  or above.

I know I can get the value of rsi with the IRSI() function. But how can I detect when ema 50 is at rsi level 90. or when ema 50 is at rsi level 10?

Comment: I have edited my question bove for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How possible is it to get the price of currency pair when RSI is at level 70, 80, or 90"*

***Short version:*** there is no way to get it "from" RSI level

---

### Why?

Read the graph and check, how many times the RSI-indicator touched or crossed the level of 30% ( on the "oversold" end of the interval of 0..100 percent scale )

[image]

Now, for each that moment in time, see the actual `Close[i]`. Are they all the same or do they differ for each such moment in time, when *`iRSI() == 30%`*?

They are different, and a lot, aren't they?

That is the reason one can never say an actual `Close[i]` just from an `iRSI()`-level.

Q.E.D.

Comment: seems you did not understand my question very well, i have edited the question now for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
double AUDJPYRSID = NormalizeDouble(iRSI("AUDJPY", 
PERIOD_D1,14,PRICE_CLOSE,0),0);
double AUDCADDLOW=0;

if(AUDCADRSID==30)
{
  AUDCADDLOW=GetCurrentPrice("AUDCAD","ask");
}

double GetCurrentPrice(string symbol, string type)
{    
 double price=0.0; 
 if(type=="bid")
 {
   price=MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_BID);
 }
 else
 {
   price=MarketInfo(symbol, MODE_ASK);
 }
 return price;
}
```

Comment: There is no such function GetCurrentPrice() in MQL4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is nothing unclear here